# Преобразование Xml файла с помощью xslt. Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Доброго времени суток дамы и господа. Имеется xml файл следующего вида :

```
<entries>
  <entry>
     <field>значение поля field</field>
 </entry>
  ...
   <entry>
    <field>значение поля field</field>
  </entry>
</entries>
  (с N вложенных элементов <entry>)
```

Надо его привести к

```
<entries>
    <entry field="значение поля field">
   ...
     <entry field="значение поля field">
</entries>
    (с N вложенных элементов <entry>)
```

Да, тут есть подобные вопросы, но меня интересует не результат, а как сделать это в приложении, через `IDEA`. У меня программа создает файл `XML` в первичном виде, потом сама его преобразовывает, поэтому мне нужно преобразование сделать именно с помощью средств языка. Гуглил, не нашел нигде работы через `java`, везде один чистый `xml` или `xslt`.

UPD. Помогите написать xslt файл, пробую сам по примерам из гугла, не получается нужного формата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Даже интересно, как вы гуглили. По запросу "java xslt" первая же ссылка - [пример из официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/transformingXML.html).

```
public class XslTransform {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("article1a.xsl"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
        Source xml = new StreamSource(new File("article1.xml"));
        transformer.transform(xml, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="entries">
    <entries>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </entries>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry>
      <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </entry>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: откуда взялся xsl файл в этом примере? Мне его нужно создать еще где то,  точнее программа должна у меня должна это делать.

Comment: Зачем создавать xsl в программе? Обычно его пишут один раз и потом применяют множество раз к входящих xml-документам.

Comment: А мне нужно создать xsl по моему примеру, или что то вроде универсальной схемы,  как он должен выглядеть, чтоб отформатировать правильно мой xml?

Comment: То есть суть вопроса не в том, как произвести трансформацию в Java, а в том, как написать xslt?

Comment: Да, вы правы, я выхожу за рамки вопроса. Дальше сам постараюсь сделать. Спасибо, вы мне очень помогли.